# How to reset the terminal emulator from tmux?

Tags: terminal, tmux

I want to "clear" the tmux pane completely. When I do something like

```
bind-key C send-keys "clear && tmux clear-history" \; send-keys "Enter"
```

suggested in  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543684/how-can-i-clear-scrollback-buffer-in-tmux, I am able to clear the scrollback buffer and get a clean screen.

However when I do Shift+PageUp and Shift+PageDown I am able to see the previous output from the terminal emulator itself (not tmux). Normally you can do `reset` command to clear the scrollback history of the terminal emulator.

Is it possible to `reset` the Terminal Emulator from tmux? Along with the above scrollback clear?

Couple of workaround suggested are:

1) To keep `Urxvt.saveLines: 0` or start `Urxvt -sl 0` - This is logical since you don't need Terminal Emulator's scrollback if you are  in tmux.

2) Detach, reset and re-attach tmux - This seems cumbersome.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49886/tmux-status-bar-corrupted-after-catting-a-binary-file-how-to-reset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `printf "\033c" > $client_tty`, where `$client_tty` is the TTY that the tmux client is running on. `\033c` is the escape sequence for the ANSI reset command.

You can list all connected clients with their TTYs with `tmux list-clients`. Limit it to a specific session with `-t $session_name`, and to outputting only the TTY with `-F '#{client_tty}'`. Thus, to reset all connected tmux clients, you want something like:

```
for client_tty in $(tmux list-clients -F '#{client_tty}'); do
    printf "\033c" > $client_tty
done
```

You will also want to issue `tmux refresh` on all clients you've reset this way to restore tmux to its usual state.

Comment: I just didn't understand this back then!

Comment: To be fair, I probably could have explained it better now than then. Regardless, happy to be of service!